# quit menu in the android

Tags: android

hello everyone i want to set the quit menu in my app . The problem i am facing by using         `System.exit(0);` it quit from the main acitivity but from the second activity when i press the quit button it come to first activity .

By using `moveTaskToBack(true)` it works fine but when i start the app again it bring back the activity from which i was quited not the main activity . so please suggest me the how we can quit easily from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting  `android:finishTaskOnLaunch=true` in `manifest file in every Activity Tag` and check.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

You should probably not be using `System.exit(0)` in your application. Take a look at [this awesome thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) for more guidance on the topic of 'exiting' an Android application.